# C# How can I clear a textbox when the backspace button is pressed

Tags: c#

I'm using C# and working on a Winform program, when a users clicks in a textbox and presses the backspace button I want to clear the textbox rather than delete one character at a time. How can I do this?

Many thanks
Steve

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good idea, from a usability perspective. I could cause confusion from the user, since the usual behaviour is to only delete one character.

Comment: You may consider having all of the text in the textbox appear selected whenever it gets input focus so that one press of the backspace key (or any key, if they just start typing) will clear the textbox. This is the same behavior as the address bars of most web browsers, so users will find it familiar. It may still accomplish what you want, while still retaining the ability to delete one character at a time if necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could subscribe to the [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event and clear the text of the sender:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 8)
    {
        ((TextBox)sender).Clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is a field users will be entering text into, please consider that some users (like me) have the natural inclination to hit Backspace when they make a typo.  I would find it annoying if doing that cleared everything I had just typed in.

As an alternative, you could add this behavior if they did a Shift-Backspace.  The code below will delete everything before the caret on a Shift-Backspace, but will also leave the expected behavior of deleting only the selection if the user has selected text:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // if shift-backspace is pressed and nothing is selected, 
    // delete everything before the caret
    if (e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Back && textBox1.SelectionLength == 0)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(textBox1.SelectionStart);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int textlength = textBox1.Text.Length;
    if (textlength > 0)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, textlength - 1);
    }
    textBox1.Focus();
    textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
    textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to the `KeyDown` event and when the pressed key equals backspace, you just have to clear the textbox.